# How to find citation tag in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, citing, zotero

I am using Zotero to collect my references then exporting them as a BibTex file and then I cite them in Latex. This is all fine but I often struggle to find the relevant citation tag.

I would like to know how to find the citation tag easily as the search function in either WinEdt or TexWorks doesn't appear to work in BibTex files. I have been selecting everything pasting in to Word and then searching that way.

Is there a Latex editor that I can use to search through the BibTex file or ideally modify the tags in Zotero (I appreciate that this is not a Zotero forum so not expecting an answer there).

Thanks in advance

Comment: By `citation tag`, do you mean `bibtex key`?

Comment: Well, `.bib` files are just text files (so are `.tex` files), so you can open them with any editor (Notepad, Notepad++, TeXworks ...), and you can search them then of course. See for example http://libguides.mit.edu/content.php?pid=55482&sid=406343 (look for *How do I cite references in my document?*).

Comment: @HarishKumar I mean the text that I need to cite: `\cite{Authors et.al}`

Comment: Have you considered switching to a dedicated `bibtex` editor like BibDesk or Jabref? Both have a zotero-like GUI, and are far easier to integrate into your LaTeX workflow. With BibDesk, you can even get TeX previews of how your bibliographical references will look when typeset.

Comment: If you're willing to forgo a flashy GUI, Emacs's [RefTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/reftex.html) mode makes it super-easy.  With RefTeX-mode enabled, all you do is type `C-c [` (where `C-c` usually means 'Crtl + c'); this pops open a little 'window', where you can specify a regular expression to search the current `.bib` file, and pull out all listing matches for you to choose from.  This list will search the *whole* entry, so if all you remember is part of the title or what journal the article was in, you just type that part in.  Easy!

Comment: @GeneG. & jon Thanks for the suggestions I shall give those a try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Winedt offers this functionality.  You type `\cite{}` then this window opens:

[image]

where you can search the entries.

[image]

Upon selecting and clicking `Insert` you will get `\cite{E.L.dasilva2000}`.

Answer (score 3):

This is another way using JabRef.

Open the `.bib` file in jabref. JabRef offers a push function for several editors. Choose your editor as below:

[image]

You can do some customization at `Options` → `Preferences` as below:

[image]

Now keep the cursor in your editor where you want to insert the `cite` command. Go to jabref and select the bib entry to be inserted and press the push button. The `\cite{key}` will be inserted in the editor.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend doing this in Zotero itself. You can do so most easily using the "[Zotero better bibtex" add-on](https://github.com/friflaj/zotero-better-bibtex). The add-on adds two key functionalities to Zotero's bib(la)tex handling
1. It adds a function (technically an export translator) to Zotero that allows you to get bibtex citekeys from Zotero items via simple drag&drop
2. It allows you to specify custom citekeys in Zoter's "Extra" field.

With those two functions in place, you can skip the text/bibtex editor entirely. See the add-ons github page for detailed documentation.

Answer (score 3):

With `sublimetext` and `LatexTools`, you can type `\cite{` Sublime Text opens a window:

[image]

Search and select in this window to insert the `\cite{bibkey}`.

Answer (score 3):

With `inlage`:

Type `cite{` and a window with all bibtex keys in the associated bib file opens like this:

[image]

Here one can choose the key and insert.